# MATLAB: datenum() returns error everytime it's called with the "formatIn" parameter

Tags: matlab, date, format

Lately MATLAB's built-in datenum() function crashes whenever I specify a *formatIn* -
even if I use the examples from the documentation.

For example:

`datenum('01-Mar-2000', 'formatIn', 'dd-mmm-yyyy')`

will give me the following error:

```
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using matlab.internal.datetime.cnv2icudf (line 143)
    Unrecognized millisecond format.  Format: formatIn.
```

I've tried it with many other date formats, and I always get this error when I specify a *formatIn*.

The only time I do **not** get this error, is when I leave out the *formatIn*.

However, leaving out *formatIn* and forcing datenum() to recognize the date format on its own, slows down my code considerably.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `formatIn` bit. This works fine, `datenum('01-Mar-2000', 'dd-mmm-yyyy')`. `formatIn` isn't a name-value argument.

Comment: datenum('01-Mar-2000') also should work fine.

Comment: @user12339314 you're right! that was it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @SivaSrinivasKolukula, though it does indeed work fine, as bluebox correctly stated in his question it can significantly slow down code not providing a format.

Answer (score 1):

As user @user12339314 pointed out in his comment, my mistake was that I was trying to call the function with *formatIn* as a **name-value argument** - which it isn't.

So instead of

`datenum('01-Mar-2000', 'formatIn', 'dd-mmm-yyyy')`

it should be

`datenum('01-Mar-2000', 'dd-mmm-yyyy')`